# Prove that B is a basis iff every vector in V has a unique decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing

Proposition statement: Let $V$ be a vector space and let $B=\{u_1\cdots u_n\}$ be a subset of $V$. $B$ is a basis of $V$ if and only if every element $v\in V$ admits a unique decomposition of the form $v=a_1u_1+\dots+a_nu_n$.

I must make a proof working backward starting with assuming every vector in $V$ has a unique decomposition. Please note this is my first proof ever (just beginning my second linear algebra class) and I am open to criticism on my use of symbols, formatting, terminology, or logic. I post this admitting that there is almost certainly an inconsistency in my writing.

My idea here is to first start with the statement that a unique combination of elements in (to be proven) basis $B=\{u_1\cdots u_n\}$ exists for all vectors in $V$. From this, I will attempt to force the idea that $B$ is a basis $V$. I will do this by first proving that $V\subseteq span(B)$, then proving that $B$ is linearly independent. Here goes.

Assume every $v\in V$ has a unique decomposition from set $B=\{u_1\cdots u_n\}$ in the form

$v=a_1u_1+\dots+a_nu_n$

As all $v$ is composed of a linear combination of $B$, $V\subseteq span(B)$.

$0\in V$ because $V$ is a vector space. As per the initial assumption that every vector in $V$ has a unique decomposition,

$0=a_1u_1+\dots+a_nu_n$

The a set of coefficients that must always hold is $\{0, \dots, 0\}$. "Unique" gives no more room for other sets of coefficients. Seeing there is only one way to form $0$ as a linear combination of elements of $B$, $\{0, \dots, 0\}$, we can conclude that $B$ is linearly independent.

$V\subseteq span(B)$ and $B$ is linearly independent. $B$ is a basis of $V$.

Comment: Overall, your proof looks good. Although I think you have a typo: it should be $V\subset\text{span}(B)$ (and hence $V=\text{span}(B)$) and not the other way around (i.e. $\text{span}(B)\subset V$, which is always true)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for pointing that out.